# How can I apply ensemble voting to multiple OCR results

Tags: clustering, fuzzy, optical-character-recognition, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I have to OCR some text, it is some laser engraved characters on leather.
As the well known OCR frameworks tend to make mistakes I decided to use them all then make an ensemble using there results. The problem is that since the words don't exist in any kind of dictionnary I can't just check them up, and do some autocrrect.

A simple Levenshtein distance calculation doesn't work well enough. Since it doesn't tell me which word should be kept.

I am currently using affinity propagation to cluster the outputs, but it doesn't always work well.

Do you have any advice ?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So your question is about spelling correction?

Comment: yes, but without having a dictionary since these are serial words (Numbers and chars)/ 
hat's why I thought about doing multiple predictions then doing an ensemble voting.